# Table cell width doesnt work for just one cell! How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, html-table, stylesheet

> I have this code for a table and all my widths for my table work except for the last search function cell which is suppose to have a width of 42.5%, but shows 20%. I am not too sure what is going wrong.

```html
<table class="mytable-body">
  <tr>
    <td height=50px style="background-color: #4472C4" colspan="4"><a href="C:\Users\shvan\Documents\MEA-VIA-Interface\Homepage_French.html">Français</a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=20%> <img src="VIA_Logo_2.png" /></td>
    <td width=60%>
      <div class="header1">
        <h1>CAE AT YOUR HAND</h1>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width=20%> <img src="LOGO_RGB.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=15% style="background-color: #4472C4" rowspan="2">
      <label>
   <h2>Our Recommended Favorites</h2>
   <select size=9 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();">
   </select>
   </label>
    </td>
    <td width=42.5%>
      <input type="text" id="mysearchInput" onkeyup="mysearchFunction()" placeholder="Search for start location..." title="Location">
      <!--the seperate code not working-->
      <label><select size=3 id="myList-1" class="list-content"></select></label>
    </td>
    <td width=42.5%>
      <input type="text" id="mysearchInput2" onkeyup="mysearchFunction2()" placeholder="Search for end location..." title="Location">
      <label><select size=3 id="myList-2" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture2();"></select></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width=70% style="background-color: aliceblue">
      <div id="qrcode"></div>
      <div id="qrcode2"></div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML doesn't make sense.

For one you need to have the same number of cells (or add up the colspans to the same number) in each row:

- In the first row you have a single cell with a colspan of **4**.
- In the second row you have **3** cells.
- In the third row you have 3 cells, one with a colspan of 2, which totals to **4** (2 + 1 + 1)
- In the forth row you have a single cell with a colspan of **2**.

All those bold numbers **must** be identical for a table.

---

Then the whole point of tables is that the cells form columns are always the same width.

Currently you have (for example):

- In the second row the first two cells have a total width of **80%** (20% + 60%)
- In the third row the first cell with colspan of 2 has a width of **15%**.
- In the fourth row the first cell with colspan of 2 has a width of **70%**.

Again, all those bold numbers **must** be identical.

Also all percentages per row need to add up to 100% (or have at least one cell without a width which will then take up the rest of the space).

---

It seems you are trying to miss-use a table for layout. Tables are for tabular data. For page layout look at CSS grids, but you'll want to use a separate grid for each of your "rows".

---

One more thing: Don't leave out quotes around HTML attribute values. It will lead to errors.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the 'colspan' attribute to make a table with a divergent number of cells in each row.  Also I'd recommend using CSS instead of the ancient "height=50px" notation.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="height: 50px; background-color: #4472C4" colspan="4"><a href="C:\Users\shvan\Documents\MEA-VIA-Interface\Homepage_French.html">Français</a> </td>
  </tr>
```